# Laravel convert SQL retrieve into a string

Tags: php, laravel

I have a retrieve statement that goes like this

```
$training = $this->training
            ->Join('training_schedules','trainings.id','=','training_schedules.training_id')
            ->select('trainings.title','training_schedules.start_date')
            ->where('training_schedules.id','=',$schedule_id)
            ->get()->first();
    
        $spd->registerRowFormatter( $formatter );
        $spd->saveExcel('training_participants', 'Participants List of '.$training);
```

Which return the result

```
Participants List of {"title":"Pelatihan","start_date":"2021-02-24 15:44:00"}
```

Anyone have a clue about what should I do to  get `Participant list of Pelatihan | (start_date)` as my result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just get the properties?

```php
$spd->saveExcel(
    'training_participants',
    'Participants List of '.$training->title.' | ('.$training->start_date.')'
);
```

Or using `"`:

```
$spd->saveExcel(
    'training_participants',
    "Participants List of {$training->title} | ({$training->start_date})"
);
```

Comment: Yeaahh, i miss that.
It's working. thanks a lot!